# ExecuteNonQuery throws ORA-1722 in Oracle Number type

Tags: asp.net, oracle11g

I have this Table "T" in Oracle 11g(11.2.0.1.0).

```
CD NVARCHAR2(20) Primary Key
,VAL NUMBER(1)
```

When Update, It's throws ORA-1722.

```
_factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.DataAccess.Client")
...(Createconnection, CreateAdapter,CreateCommand, Transaction)
_command.CommandText="UPDATE T SET VAL = :VAL WHERE CD = :CD"
dim p1 as DbParameter = _command.CreateParameter()
p1.DbType = DbType.String
p1.Value = "AX-0001"
p1.ParameterName = "CD"
_command.Parameters.Add(p1)
dim p2 as DbParameter = _command.CreateParameter()
p2.DbType = DbType.Decimal
p2.Value = 3
p2.ParameterName = "VAL"
_command.Parameters.Add(p2)
_command.ExecuteNonQuery() ' ->throw exception
```

But, Select query returned correct DataTable.

```
_factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.DataAccess.Client")
...(Createconnection, CreateAdapter,CreateCommand, Transaction)
_command.CommandText="SELECT CD, VAL FROM T WHERE CD = :CD AND VAL = :VAL"
dim p1 as DbParameter = _command.CreateParameter()
p1.DbType = DbType.String
p1.Value = "AX-0001"
p1.ParameterName = "CD"
_command.Parameters.Add(p1)
dim p2 as DbParameter = _command.CreateParameter()
p2.DbType = DbType.Decimal
p2.Value = 3
p2.ParameterName = "VAL"
_command.Parameters.Add(p2)
_adapter.SelectCommand = _command
_command.ExecuteNonQuery() ' ->success
```

what I wrong?
I tried to modify CreateParameter to New OracleParameter and DbType to OracleDbType, but it throws ORA-1722 too.

Add more...(1/20 02:04 GMT)

I set more parameters "Size", "Precision", "Scale" by my function, but it's not yet resolved throws ORA-1722.

```
AddDecimalParam("VAL", 3, 1,0)

Public Overridable Sub AddDecimalParam(name As String, value As Object, precision As Byte, scale As Byte)
    Dim p As DbParameter = _command.CreateParameter()
    p.ParameterName = name
    p.DbType = DbType.Decimal
    p.Value = value
    p.Size = precision + scale
    p.Precision = precision    ' -> can't change value! keep "0".
    p.Scale = scale
    p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

    _command.Parameters.Add(p)
End Sub
```

In this way, I get same result.

```
AddOraDecimalParam("HANBAISAKI_MONEY", row("HANBAISAKI_MONEY"), 1, 0)

Public Overridable Sub AddOraDecimalParam(name As String, value As Object, precision As Byte, scale As Byte)

    Dim p As Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter = New OracleParameter(name, OracleDbType.Decimal, precision + scale, ParameterDirection.Input, True, precision, scale, name, DataRowVersion.Proposed, Nothing)
    p.Value = value

    _command.Parameters.Add(p)
End Sub
```

Comment: Because your parameter in oracle is *number(1)*, but you are sending *decimal*. *Decimal*, by definition, is *number(38, 0)*. So even if it's value is 3, it's type's range much more than you have in your query.

Comment: This error throws when you are trying to convert a string into a number. can you post your "update" and "select" query to point out the root cause?

Comment: In query, I changed table name and column name, but that's all. I write these code simply for Sample in my team. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this probrem.
ODP.NET use parameters order of decralation not name in default.
I must set "command.BindByName" is true.

I modified my DbUtility.

```
Protected _factory As System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory

Protected _connection As DbConnection = Nothing
Protected _adapter As DbDataAdapter = Nothing
Protected _command As DbCommand = Nothing

Public Sub New(target as String)
    _factory = System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(target)

    _connection = _factory.CreateConnection()
    _connection.ConnectionString = DbConfig.getIns().ConnectionString
    _connection.Open()

    _adapter = _factory.CreateDataAdapter
    _command = _connection.CreateCommand
    _command.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    If TypeOf _command Is OracleCommand Then
        DirectCast(_command, OracleCommand).BindByName = True
    End If

End Sub
```

thank you.